# Ebproof package: error on updating MikTeX v. 21.1. on Windows

Tags: errors, miktex, windows, compilation-error, ebproof

With the recent version of `ebproof` package I have an error of compilation. How is it possible to solve this problem?

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}


\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\hypo{ \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
\infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
\hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
\infer2[app]{ \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

and the `.log` is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1 32-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:/Users/utente/Desktop/new question/Test2.tex"
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\mathtools.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/latex-tools\calc.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\mhsetup.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty")))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ebproof\ebproof.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex"))
)
No file Test2.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsb.fd")

! LaTeX3 Error: Use \box_set_eq_drop:N not \box_set_eq_clear:NN deprecated on
(LaTeX3)        2021-01-01. For 6 months after that date one can restore a
(LaTeX3)        deprecated command by loading the expl3 package with the
(LaTeX3)        option 'undo-recent-deprecations'.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.10 \infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
                                          
?
```

**EDIT:** `.log` file.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 21.1 32-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.19)  22 JAN 2021 22:49
entering extended mode
**./Test2.tex
(Test2.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@section=\count178
\c@subsection=\count179
\c@subsubsection=\count180
\c@paragraph=\count181
\c@subparagraph=\count182
\c@figure=\count183
\c@table=\count184
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\mathtools.sty"
Package: mathtools 2020/03/24 v1.24 mathematical typesetting tools

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/latex-tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count185
\calc@Bcount=\count186
\calc@Adimen=\dimen139
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen140
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count187
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/mathtools\mhsetup.sty"
Package: mhsetup 2017/03/31 v1.3 programming setup (MH)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsmath.sty"
Package: amsmath 2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amstext.sty"
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsgen.sty"
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen141
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsbsy.sty"
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsmath\amsopn.sty"
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count188
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count189
\leftroot@=\count190
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
\classnum@=\count191
\DOTSCASE@=\count192
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box47
\strutbox@=\box48
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count193
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count194
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count195
\dspbrk@lvl=\count196
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count197
\column@=\count198
\maxfields@=\count199
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2923.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2924.
)
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\('isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\)'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\['isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
LaTeX Info: Thecontrolsequence`\]'isalreadyrobust on input line 130.
\g_MT_multlinerow_int=\count266
\l_MT_multwidth_dim=\dimen150
\origjot=\skip55
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustabove_dim=\dimen151
\l_MT_shortvdotswithinadjustbelow_dim=\dimen152
\l_MT_above_intertext_sep=\dimen153
\l_MT_below_intertext_sep=\dimen154
\l_MT_above_shortintertext_sep=\dimen155
\l_MT_below_shortintertext_sep=\dimen156
\xmathstrut@box=\box49
\xmathstrut@dim=\dimen157
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amssymb.sty"
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\amsfonts.sty"
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 98.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/ebproof\ebproof.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2021-01-09 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def"
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-01-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count267
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse-generic.tex"))
Package: ebproof 2020/08/19 v2.1 EB's proof trees
\l__ebproof_separation_dim=\dimen158
\l__ebproof_rule_margin_dim=\dimen159
\l__ebproof_rule_thickness_dim=\dimen160
\l__ebproof_rule_separation_dim=\dimen161
\l__ebproof_rule_dash_length_dim=\dimen162
\l__ebproof_rule_dash_space_dim=\dimen163
\l__ebproof_label_separation_dim=\dimen164
\l__ebproof_label_axis_dim=\dimen165
\g__ebproof_register_int=\count268
\l__ebproof_transit_dim=\dimen166
\g__ebproof_level_int=\count269
\g__ebproof_stack_box=\box51
\g__ebproof_box_1=\box52
\g__ebproof_box_2=\box53
\g__ebproof_box_3=\box54
\g__ebproof_box_4=\box55
)
No file Test2.aux.
\openout1 = `Test2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count270
\scratchdimen=\dimen167
\scratchbox=\box56
\nofMPsegments=\count271
\nofMParguments=\count272
\everyMPshowfont=\toks21
\MPscratchCnt=\count273
\MPscratchDim=\dimen168
\MPnumerator=\count274
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count275
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks22
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-base.sty"
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen169
\Gin@req@width=\dimen170
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+msa on input line 9.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/amsfonts\umsa.fd"
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+ms
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jan, 28<sup>th</sup> 2021 update: the maintainer sent an update for `ebproof` to CTAN, so you can update (it may take a day or two for your mirror to update) and then you can remove the `undo-recent-deprecations` line.

---

The `ebproof` needs an update to replace the deprecated `\box_set_eq_clear:NN` by `\box_set_eq_drop:N`.  As the error message suggests, for some time you can work around that by loading `expl3` with `undo-recent-deprecations` before loading `ebproof`:

```latex
\RequirePackage[undo-recent-deprecations]{expl3}% <<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS LINE BEFORE EBPROOF

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{ebproof}


\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\hypo{ \Gamma, A &\vdash B }
\infer1[abs]{ \Gamma &\vdash A\to B }
\hypo{ \Gamma \vdash A }
\infer2[app]{ \Gamma \vdash B }
\end{prooftree}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hii very kind Phelype...I have put the expl3 package but is does't work. I have read all the manual Version 2.1 – Released 2020-08-19 but before of 2021-1-1 I have not had any problems. Do you think that this package must be changed? My best regards and +1 surely.

Comment: @Sebastiano The error appeared this year because that command was deprecated on 2021-01-01, so before it was fine.  But the MWE in my answer works on my machine (TeX Live 2020).  What does not work for you? Can you show the `.log`?

Comment: I use TeXworks. Where can I find the .log? In the meantime I'm searching.

Comment: @Sebastiano It's in the same folder as your `.tex` file.  The same thing as in your question, but with the line `\RequirePackage[undo-recent-deprecations]{expl3}` at the beginning

Comment: Found :-) ...I not see often the .log file :-( excuse me very much. See my edit.

Comment: @Sebastiano You didn't load `expl3` (not before `ebproof`).  Add the line `\RequirePackage[undo-recent-deprecations]{expl3}` at the very beginning of your document.

Comment: In your opinion should the author or creator of the package be written to for this problem?

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, [this is taken care of](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/56836247#56836247)

Comment: I have seen now that there is `ebproof` package  
Version 2.1.1 – Released 2021-01-28. Thank you very much to you and to Ulrike.